# NGINX,PHP server is slow

Tags: nginx, server, mariadb, php-7.2

I'm using a good performance vps. 1gbps internet,4core,16gb ram 500gb ssd. My phpmyadmin page need 15s+ ,the laravel page 35s+ to open. I'm running nginx,php7.2-fpm and mariadb. What should I do?

Comment: You have to profile your application properly. Check latency on the database connection as well.

Comment: How many SQL queries on those pages?  Tables in your database?  Other metrics.